# SSL and URL Rewrite Timing Issue

Tags: ssl, iis, url-rewriting

I have a wildcard certificate for *.domainname.com.  I know that TLS sessions are set up before any URL rewrite rules happen.  I have the URL test.domainname.com working fine and redirecting to https.  But what happens when someone may type in ***www***.test.domainname.com.  Now they get "Your connection is not private" because the www adds one more level and makes the wildcard certificate invalid. I would like to strip out the www with a rule but the SSL check happens first.  How do people handle this so that all URLs  end up at the same place with no errors?!? I am using Windows Server and IIS...

Comment: Get a certificate which includes `www.test.domainname.com` if you fear that users might use this name explicitly with the `https://` method. If they use it only for `http://` (which is the default when using no explicit protocol) it should be no problem though, i.e. you can redirect it to something with proper `https://` and without the `www`.

Comment: It seems like IIS only allows 1 certificate per site and for these sites I need a wildcard certificate.  How do I create 1 CSR to allow for test.domainname.com and www.test.domainname.com?  This gets very confusing.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: A certificate can have multiple SAN with wildcard and fixed name together. See for example the certificate for google.de, which includes `*.google.de`, `*.google.com.tw` and many more wildcards together with non-wildcards like `google.de`, `www.goo.gl` etc

Comment: SSL/TLS handshake happens earlier than URL rewriting, you must present the web browser with valid certificates for both `www.test.domainname.com` and `test.domainname.com`. Otherwise, the web browser will generate a warning when it detects no valid certificate.